# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

I just upgraded kali linux and mysql has been broken ever since. after I start `mysql` & `apache2` services I run the command `mysql` then I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I check to see if I have `mysql-server` installed, So I run `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

and this is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.1:i386 mysql-common mariadb-server-10.1

E: Package 'mysql-server-5.5' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did you run "sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5" or just "apt-get install mysql-server-5.5" ?

Comment: @duDE Yeah tried that. Still the same message.

Comment: So your problem is not "Can't connect to local MySQL" but "Can't install MySQL" ?

Comment: @duDE it was running perfectly fine before I upgrade my kali. So I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried to re-install MySQL (sudo apt-get purge)? Take a look: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql

Comment: Did you actually look at the logs for mysql to see where its startup fails? Have you done any diagnostic in that regard? Otherwise, as you can see by that output, that package is obsolete for your update. Likely some bindings/libraries changed or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I face the similar error. It's because mysql-server is not installed. But in latest Kali installation the MariaDB for is used instead of MySQL. You can install the server using,

```
apt install mariadb-server
```